# Node Express server not send messages with whatsapp-web-js

Tags: node.js, express

i have a problem with my custom server, i'm trying to setup an api that send whatsapp messages in react as a frontend.

So, i have actually a route that send the QR to the frontend (working fine), a route that handle the authentication event (working fine) and

PROBLEM HERE:

...a route that send a message to a specific number (NOT WORK)

here my server code...what i'm doing wrong? if i launch a POST request to the endpoint on postman, i get an infinite loading (no errors).

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const fs = require('fs')
const { Client, LocalAuth } = require('whatsapp-web.js')



const authStrategy = new LocalAuth({
    clientId: 'adminSession',
})

const worker = `${authStrategy.dataPath}/session-admin/Default/Service Worker`
if (fs.existsSync(worker)) {
    fs.rmdirSync(worker, { recursive: true })
}

const client = new Client({
    takeoverOnConflict: true,
    authStrategy,
})

const sessionData = {
    client: 'admin',
    session: true,
    qrCodeScanned: true,
}

client.on('authenticated', (session) => {
    fs.writeFile(
        'waSession.json',
        JSON.stringify(sessionData),
        'utf-8',
        (err) => {
            if (!err) {
                console.log('Session saved on disk...')
            }
        }
    )
})

router.get('/whatsapp/auth', async (req, res) => {
    const dir = './waSession.json'
    fs.readFile(dir, (err, data) => {
        if (data.length === 0) {
            return res.status(200).json({
                message: 'You need to login first',
            })
        } else {
            return res.status(200).json({
                message: 'You are logged in.',
            })
        }
    })
})

router.get('/whatsapp', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        client.on('qr', (qr) => {
            res.status(200).send({
                message: 'Connect whatsapp with this qr-code',
                qrCode: qr,
            })
        })
        await client.initialize()
        res.status(404)
    } catch (err) {
        res.send(err)
    }
})

router.post('/whatsapp/send', async (req, res) => {
    const { phoneNumber, message } = req.body
    try {
        client.on('ready', async () => {
            const number = phoneNumber
            const text = message
            const chatId = number.substring(1) + '@c.us'
            await client.sendMessage(chatId, text)
        })
        await client.initialize()
        res.json('Messaggio inviato')
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(404).send(err)
        await client.destroy()
    }
})

module.exports = router
```

Comment: Must the `client` really be initialized both during `GET /whatsapp` and `POST /whatsapp/send`? Or does the second initialization never finish?

Comment: this is what i've figured out from various docs...what is the error that i made? can you be more specific?

Comment: The `client.on` statements per request also accumulate, I doubt that is correct. Can you link the relevant documentation?

Comment: https://wwebjs.dev/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `Client` represents one authenticated WhatsApp user, and you have only one global variable `client`. This implies that all incoming requests will represent the same WhatsApp user, even if several different real users send requests to your server in parallel. This is probably not what you intend.

I suggest that you use [`express-session`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session) to associate every `client` with a session. Then a user needs to create a `client` and authenticate it only *once* during a session. All subsequent requests in the same session will re-use that `client`, and the `client.on(...)` and `client.initialize()` commands will not be repeated.

Comment: Actually I have only 1 user that have access to this functionality…only 1 admin user, is a private app

Comment: Still, don't repeat the the client.on(...) and client.initialize() commands for that user.

Comment: Ok but if I put the client.inizialize st the top…all the endpoints breaks, and don’t work anything